# How to do a glide reflection?

Tags: linear-algebra

Problem: Find the formula for a glide reflection along the line x + y = 1 by distance 2 in the direction of increasing x.

Answer: [answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wkis.png)

- Please explain the process of getting that answer. I am spooked by the fact that it is not reflected along the line x=y, x-axis, or y-axis. I specifically do not understand how ... (x - (1 0)^T) + (1 0)^T ... was generated.

Comment: Geometrically the process is the move the line to the origin, reflect, then move the origin back. The $x-(1,0)^T$ moves the line to the origin. Matrix multiplication reflects, then the $+(1,0)^T$ moves it back.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please edit your answer using MathJax (it also would be better if you wrote down the answer here without the link), as it will be easier to read.
Here's the guide how to do it: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference